# Linq query : Translate local variable reference

Tags: c#, linq

I have a situation where I need to translate the local variables reference in a linq query to its values.
For this I'm using this class to do a translate local variable reference in a query :

```
public static class Evaluator 
{
    public static Expression PartialEval(Expression expression, Func<Expression, bool> fnCanBeEvaluated) 
    {
        return new SubtreeEvaluator(new Nominator(fnCanBeEvaluated).Nominate(expression)).Eval(expression);
    }

    public static Expression PartialEval(Expression expression) 
    {
        return PartialEval(expression, Evaluator.CanBeEvaluatedLocally);
    }

    private static bool CanBeEvaluatedLocally(Expression expression)
    {
        return expression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Parameter;
    }

    class SubtreeEvaluator: ExpressionVisitor
    {
        HashSet<Expression> candidates;

        internal SubtreeEvaluator(HashSet<Expression> candidates) 
        {
            this.candidates = candidates;
        }

        internal Expression Eval(Expression exp) 
        {
            return this.Visit(exp);
        }

        protected override Expression Visit(Expression exp) 
        {
            if (exp == null) 
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (this.candidates.Contains(exp)) 
            {
                return this.Evaluate(exp);
            }

            return base.Visit(exp);
        }

        private Expression Evaluate(Expression e) 
        {
            if (e.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant) 
            {
                return e;
            }

            LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(e);
            Delegate fn = lambda.Compile();

            return Expression.Constant(fn.DynamicInvoke(null), e.Type);
        }
    }

    class Nominator : ExpressionVisitor 
    {
        Func<Expression, bool> fnCanBeEvaluated;
        HashSet<Expression> candidates;
        bool cannotBeEvaluated;

        internal Nominator(Func<Expression, bool> fnCanBeEvaluated) 
        {
            this.fnCanBeEvaluated = fnCanBeEvaluated;
        }

        internal HashSet<Expression> Nominate(Expression expression) 
        {
            this.candidates = new HashSet<Expression>();
            this.Visit(expression);
            return this.candidates;
        }

        protected override Expression Visit(Expression expression) 
        {
            if (expression != null) 
            {
                bool saveCannotBeEvaluated = this.cannotBeEvaluated;
                this.cannotBeEvaluated = false;
                base.Visit(expression);

                if (!this.cannotBeEvaluated) 
                {
                    if (this.fnCanBeEvaluated(expression)) 
                    {
                        this.candidates.Add(expression);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        this.cannotBeEvaluated = true;
                    }
                }

                this.cannotBeEvaluated |= saveCannotBeEvaluated;
            }

            return expression;
        }
    }
}
```

And after to translate local variable reference , is used like this :

```
public class DbQueryProvider : QueryProvider 
{
    // …

    private string Translate(Expression expression) 
    {
        expression = Evaluator.PartialEval(expression);
        return new QueryTranslator().Translate(expression);
    }
}
```

For example if I have this expression :

```
string ct = "London";
var query = db.Customers.Where(c => c.City == ct);
```

the returned expression after translation will be :

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Customers) AS T WHERE (City = 'London')
```

The code is working ok , with all the types of variables , except of DateTime.
In my database I save only the Date part ( without time ) , for example 02/03/2012.

Now if I have this query :

```
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2012");
var query = db.Orders.Where(c => c.dt == dt1);
```

If I try to translate , the returned expression is :

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Orders) AS T WHERE (dt = '01/01/2012 12:00:00 AM')
```

As you can see the translated query contains the time at the end , and my query everytime return no records.

What can I do ?

Comment: What is the type of the column in your database?

Comment: That's because a `DateTime` consists of both a `Date` and a `Time`

Comment: `DateTime dt1 = "01/01/2012";` does not compile. Post real code please.

Comment: In my sql server  database the type of column is Date

Comment: If your column is a `DATE` column on the SQL server, and not a `DATETIME` column, I'd be surprised that `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Orders) AS T WHERE (dt = '01/01/2012 12:00:00 AM')` wouldn't bring anything back (assuming there is at least one row for that date)

Comment: Why do you have a `ExpressionVisitor`? You aren't doing anything special. Have you taken a look at the `SQL` that is generated, if you are using EF6 there are suitable injection points for that. Also double check the connection string to your `DbContext.Database.Connection`, as it could be that EF created a new empty database for you...

Comment: @Aron  EF is not creating a new database , because if I use the same query using a constant Date ( and not a variable )  directly in the query , everything is ok.

Answer (score -2):

```
var query = db.Orders.Where(c => c.dt == dt1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Comment: I try several thing , but it seems that the problem is not how the variable that holds the date is formatted , but how it's translated later.